# Visual Studio, Updating website address

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm putting web browser into my program. So far, I am able to get the page to navigate to the address I type into my TextBox1. However, if i press the back button or forward button, the TextBox1 does not change to the correct website address. How do I write the code so that TextBox1 always shows the correct website name. Please advice, thanks.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: wats all those? I think I'm using Window Forms

Comment: Visual Studio supports lots of different technologies for creating applications. Windows Forms (abbreviated WinForms) is one of them. You pick the one you want when you create a new project. It's important to specify the one that you're using when asking a question, rather than just that you're using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using the [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) and displaying the current URL in a [`TextBox` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx).

In that case, you need to handle the [`Navigated` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) of your `WebBrowser` control, and inside of that event handler method, update the [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk.aspx) of your `TextBox` control.

The `Navigated` event is raised when the `WebBrowser` control has navigated to a new document and has begun loading it. The documentation tells you all of the properties/methods that can trigger the `WebBrowser` control to begin navigating to a new page.

The documentation even contains a sample for exactly what you're doing:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.Text = e.Url.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How can i even express my gratitude?? tell me.

Comment: But the site despise me and don't allow me up vote the answer =(